# -Innostudio- How to stop execution after delete or if any error occurred ,it keep going inside 'sorter' on_sort callback

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I am using Creative Dream JQuery Filer (now known as innostudio fileuploader)
we have appended files and doing sorting, But When we upload any invalid image or invalid no. of images, then user get error alert,after that, it goes inside onSort callback (Look like a bug):

Sorting section:

```
'sorter'=> array( 
     'onSort'=> "js:function(list, listEl, parentEl, newInputEl, inputEl) {
         updateListingIndex(list);
     }" 
 ),
```

And Remove/delete file section is given below :-

```
'onRemove' => "js:function(item){   
     $.ajax({
         url : '/sell/ImageDelete',
         data: { 
             'image_value'   : item.data.image_value, 
             'listingId'     : '$listingId'
         },
         method: 'POST',
         success :function (result) {
             data = JSON.parse(result);
             if(data.result != '1') {
                 $('.ListingImage-error').html(data.error);
             }
         }
     });               
 }",
```

I believe there is no point of calling sort function after error happens, return false is not working,

Answer (score 0):

My assumption would be more for the UI than anything. So when the item is removed, it would sort the items back to what it should be index wise. You could potentially disable it via a variable such as

```js
var sorter = array( 
     'onSort' => "js:function(list, listEl, parentEl, newInputEl, inputEl) {
                      updateListingIndex(list);
                  }" 
 );

// Then something along these lines

'sorter'=> sorter,
'onRemove' => "js:function(item){
                   $.ajax({
                       url : '/sell/ImageDelete',
                       data: { 
                           'image_value'   : item.data.image_value, 
                           'listingId'     : '$listingId'
                       },
                       method: 'POST',
                       success :function (result) {
                           data = JSON.parse(result);
                           if(data.result != '1') {
                               $('.ListingImage-error').html(data.error);
                               sorter = false;
                           }
                       }
                   });               
               }",
```

then when it fails just change sorter to false.

Though I'm unsure if it'll work BEFORE the onSort function runs but worth a shot.